# OpenStreetMap in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, openstreetmap

I'm interested in using OpenStreetMap in a web application developed using ASP.NET.

Anyone knows if there is a control, library or wrapper for using OpenStreetMap in ASP.NET? (C#, not using Javascript).

Comment: Not sure if this helps - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/GMapNET.aspx?msg=2956650. Would you mind letting me know if you do find ASP.NET wrapper?

Comment: Hello sir did you manage to do Openstreetmap in Asp.net 4.0 aspx? And dynamically map lat and lon?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether they have any ASP specific tools, but [Cloudmade](http://cloudmade.com) have lots of tools & API you can use to get OpenStreetMap into your app. It's mostly done on the client though through JavaScript, so I don't think you'll find much in the way of C# tools.

I could be wrong though...

Comment: Hello sir did you manage to do Openstreetmap in Asp.net 4.0 aspx? And dynamically map lat and lon?

Answer (score 0):

[BruTile](http://brutile.codeplex.com/) is a C# library for displaying a slippy map. It can be used on the web, displaying via silverlight.

In my opinion a silverlight requirement is not a sensible choice for a public website, and not very sensible for internal use either from a long term perspective, so this isn't a great solution. But this is the only thing I'm aware of which matches what you're asking for.

"not using Javascript" is a curious restriction, since most embedded web maps use javascript. Perhaps you mean *you* don't want to work with any javascript, but the website can use it. In which case...  I'm still not aware of any C# solution, but a library which wraps OpenLayers or [one of the other alternatives](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Deploying_your_own_Slippy_Map), hiding all javascript development from you, would be very feasible. Someone should build such a thing! In the meantime, the javascript to display a slippy map is quite simple I promise :-)

The other approach might be a [Static Map Image](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Static_map_images) generating library which fetches tile images, stitches them into a single image and caches it locally for you to display in an <img> tag. Again such a thing would be very feasible (easy!?) to build with C#. Someone should do it! In the meantime you can link to one of those services (e.g [the new one from MapQuest](http://devblog.mapquest.com/2011/05/11/get-creative-with-the-open-static-maps-api/)) directly from an <img> tag on your site. ...No javascript, and no C# either!

Comment: Hello sir did you manage to do Openstreetmap in Asp.net 4.0 aspx? And dynamically map lat and lon?