# OpenStreeMaps with ASP MVC .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openstreetmap

I would like to develop a project using OpenStreeMaps and ASP MVC. I have been googling but have not found any example, I found a library called thinkgeo but we can't afford to pay for it. Does anyone know an example of OpenStreetMaps with ASP MVC?

Comment: This question seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156641/openstreetmap-in-asp-net

Comment: That thread is not what I am looking for, I want to use ASP MVC, OpenStreeMap and render the graphic map with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't clear what do you want to use ASP.net. Routing, for POI-s, searching?
If you want to embed an OSM map and show some places or routes on it, see OpenLayers:
http://www.openlayers.org/

Answer (score 0):

All of the map rendering stuff happens on the client side (so the ASP MVC portion of this is moot insofar as rendering the map) - you need to find yourself a good javascript map client. The one I've done this with before is leaflets:

[LefletJS Quickstart Guide](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/)

you add the relevant JS to your ASP MVC project and setup the view.cshtml to create a map. Unless the controller is telling the map where to render, JS/HTML should be all you need. If you give this a go and run into issues, please elaborate in your question above.