# How to use OpenStreetMap data .osm.pbf file

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, openstreetmap

I have downloaded OpenStreetMap data .osm.pbf file. I have not any idea how to use is in may asp.net application? Any solution?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What is your goal? Map rendering? Routing? Searching for addresses? See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop

Comment: Map rendering bro

Comment: Okay bro. What about similar questions like https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/32399/how-to-intrigrate-osm-in-aspnet-website and https://stackoverflow.com/q/4156641/1340631? Also look at available C# [Frameworks for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks).